# How to downgrade OpenJDK from 1.8 to 1.7?

Tags: openjdk

I somehow installed openJDK 1.8 by mistake. And one of my process cannot run as normal as before. I have to downgrade the OpenJDK version to 1.7 but I am unable to do it.

Can someone provide a solution?

Comment: Why are you unable to downgrade?

Comment: Which process cannot run on JDK8? You could provide more details and we will help to run this software without global downgrade. It is better to provide jdk7 for this particular software and let other processes to use new jdk8

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run iDempiere, both server and client for testing. Now I cannot do anything on the setup or run the client.....so I guess I have to switch back to OpenJDK7